# Difference between hamcrest-library Matchers and hamcrest-core CoreMatchers

Tags: junit, hamcrest

It looks like the hamcrest `org.hamcrest.Matchers` class is very similar to `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers` (though it looks like `Matchers` has more). Why would I choose to use `CoreMatchers` (other than it looks like the class is slightly smaller), and why are these two classes so similar?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Hamcrest matchers are split into several modules. The "core" includes the most basic matchers and abstract classes required for building other matchers. `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers` includes the factory methods for just these matchers. The other matchers are in the "library" module grouped by the types of objects they match and are optional. `org.hamcrest.Matchers` includes both sets of matchers.

Which should you use? I statically import everything from the latter without any trouble. Perhaps the compile times might take slightly longer, but that's never been an issue for me. I put this at the top of my unit tests in addition to the JUnit imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

This gives the best readability in the test methods.

Answer (score 11):

If you use Mockito a lot (as I do), you might be doing:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
```

or

```
static import org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

and since the `Mockito` class extends Mockito's `Matchers` class, then you can end up with conflicts between either the Matchers classes or their static methods.  Having CoreMatchers allows me to use JUnit-derived CoreMatchers in the same class as Mockito, without having to full-qualify them at their point of usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Android's JUnit tests (not connected tests), the `CoreMatcher`s seem to be available inside the already-included *junit* module, while the `Matchers` are not.

Thus, to save overhead, and to avoid importing another library, consider using the `CoreMatcher` versions of these classes if they suffice:

```
assertThat(chrome.twiddle(), is(equalTo(0)));
```

is possible using only [`CoreMatcher`s](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html).