# What's the difference between hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo() and hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo()

Tags: java, hamcrest

The documentation is identical:

- [org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#equalTo(T))
- [org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsEqual.html#equalTo(T))

Is using one version preferable to the others?

And from the comments it appears that there is a third version:
[org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalTo(T))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between hamcrest-library Matchers and hamcrest-core CoreMatchers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932941/difference-between-hamcrest-library-matchers-and-hamcrest-core-corematchers)

Answer (score 0):

in fact they are the same.

CoreMatchers calls IsEqualMatcher

```
  public static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> equalTo(T operand) {
    return org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.<T>equalTo(operand);
  }
```

To answer the question which one to use - it all depends on the code conventions employed in specific project.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped that they did actually all end up in the same place. Given that they do is there a reason to prefer one namespace over the others? Either conceptually or by convention?