# Which Hamcrest matcher to import

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, jvm, hamcrest

I am using Hamcrest in a gradle/JVM project via the `org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2` artifact which is what the [Hamcrest website recommends](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/distributables). When I go to static import a matcher, e.g. `is` or `notNullValue`, I am presented with 3 options of where to import it from. In the case of `notNullValue` these are:

- `org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers`
- `org.hamcrest.Matchers`
- `org.hamcrest.core.IsNull`

I was wondering if there was a 'best practice' one to choose?

[image: choice of imports]

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932941/difference-between-hamcrest-library-matchers-and-hamcrest-core-corematchers

Answer (score 1):

You can import all of these functions like this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant more like should you import from Matchers, CoreMatchers, or the specific package (e.g. Is.is)? You seem to have chosen Matchers - what is the reason for that?